# Rsync module path needs to be a home directory

Tags: linux, rsync

I'm trying to use rsync to backup windows servers to an rsync server. I'm having problems with rsync on the linux side though, it doesn't like symlinks.

Currently I'm trying to use the module path of `~/backup`, but rsync says that the chroot failed. I looked up what to do and saw that I needed to add the option `use chroot = no` and `munge symlinks = no`. That fixed the `@ERROR: chroot failed` but now it's telling me `@ERROR: chdir failed` and the log files say that there is no ~/backup directory. I know the user I'm authenticating with has a backup folder in his directory.

How can I fix this?

For reference I'm using a .NET port of rsync called NetSync and tunneling it over a port forwarded SSH connection generated with granados.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, tilde (~) expansion is done by the shell.  chdir() doesn't handle this.

Try an absolute path.  If you don't like that, then try using "backup" (or ./backup) on the assumption that after login, the current directory will be set to the user's home directory.

Comment: Because a absolute path would defeat the purpose. I need the user's home directory because I want rsync to back up to the user that logged in.

Comment: Did you try the other suggestion (./backup)?

Comment: yes, 2.6.9 doesn't support relative paths. 3.0.0+ does, however the path will be relative to where the rsync daemon was executed from. I.E. not the user.

Comment: Hmmm, I just checked my rsync script and it uses a relative path with no problem at all.  The client is rsync 2.6.6 (it came with DeltaCopy), host is some kind of Linux.  I suggest double checking your assumptions about the default directory,

Comment: `rsync host:foo/` in at least 3.0+ implies ssh transport to host and since sshd will put me in ~ by default, foo/ will refer to ~/foo/ for me.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand it, it seems that your path should be /home, and that it is up to your user to move into his own directory.

There is another solution that involves declaring a module for each user, but that seems overly complex for the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit too late,  but chroot fails if the directory does not exist.  Did you check if ~/backup has actually been created?